# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on updating a pretty old app for my client, but I am not even able to run it on the simulator. It uses .xib files instead of .storyboard. When I run it, I get this error in the debug log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'
```

This is my code in App Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[AudioDatabase createDatabaseIfNeeded];

[EmailView createDatabaseIfNeeded];
[EmailView updateDatabaseIfNeeded];

if ([self isEmailView] == YES &&
    [EmailView shouldShowEmailView] == YES) {
    // the first view is the "Email View"

    [self goToEmailView];
} else {
    [self goToAudio];
}
}

- (void)goToEmailView {
InitialEmailViewController * currentView = [[InitialEmailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitialEmailViewController" bundle:nil];     

//CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//[window setFrame:rect];

CGRect appRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

[window setFrame:appRect];

[window addSubview:currentView.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)goToAudio {
NSString * currentTrack = [AudioDatabase getLastTrack];

if (currentTrack != nil) {
    lastTrack = currentTrack;
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: set lastTrack to %@", lastTrack);
}

CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[window setFrame:rect];

//CGRect appRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
//[viewController.view setFrame:appRect];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
// Override point for customization after app launch
[window addSubview:navController.view];
//[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

any advice would be great! I've looked this up and found a lot of solutions, but none have seemed to work for me.

Comment: Can you post 2 function `goToEmailView` and `goToAudio`?

Comment: You must be following a really, really old tutorial. Adding a subview to the main window hasn't been the proper way to set the main view for quite a few years now. Look into `UIWindow rootViewController`.

Comment: Like I said at the beginning of my post, "I am working on updating a pretty old app for my client". I haven't even touched the code yet..